# API design : return type should be Map or a new object holding Map

Tags: java, api-design

I am designing an API for getting some values from client, and need some help about return type of that API.

What should be the approach (this is not real code, this just the representation of real code)?

Approach 1:

```
public interface Provider {
    Map<Long, Long> getDependencies(String type);
}
```

Approach 2:

```
public interface Provider {
    Dependency getDependency(String type);
}

public class Dependency {
    private Map<Long, Long> dependency;
    public Dependency(Map<Long, Long> dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public Map<Long, Long> getDependency() {
        ImmutableMap.copyOf(dependency);
    }
}
```

#Update

To my opinion second approach is good as its open for extension.

One more question that I have is `getDependency` should me immutable or not?

Answer (score 1):

I would do whatever you believe is simpler and clearer.

As for extension I suggest you read about [YAGNI](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt). If you really can predict the future, I suggest you play the lottery.  If you can't predict the future, I suggest you not try and only do what you know you need now.